# How to check if variable was passed by reference in PHP

Tags: php, reference

Straightforward:
I want to write some code which tells if a variable was passed by reference or not.
For example:

```
<?php
function isReference($variable) {
    //return TRUE if &$something was passed
    //return FALSE if $something was passed
}
$text = 'Anything';
$a = isReference(&$text); //return TRUE
$b = isReference($test); //return FALSE
?>
```

For those who are curious - why do I need it?
Firstly I do not like to leave problems unsolved.
Secondly, I am currently enhancing by skills by writing an extension to mysqli, which would prepare statements similar to how PDO does. If anybody knows the difference between bindParam and bindValue in PDO, they know that it's a workaround of this question. I can just make two functions, but I wonder if it's possible with one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FWIW, call-time pass by reference is deprecated in 5.3 and removed in 5.4. You should not use it in new code, and your API should certainly not depend on its presence.

Comment: If it were possible with one function, I'd assume that PDO would do that, right?

Comment: Maybe creators of PDO had good reasons not to do so..

Anyway I just learnt that call-time pass-by-reference is deprecated and this was pretty helpful. Thank you lonesomeday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way to do it without using the `debug_zval_dump` function:

```
function isReference($variable) {
    $variable = array($variable);
    $arg = func_get_arg(0);
    $isRef = isset($arg[0]) && $arg === array($variable[0]);
    $variable = $variable[0];

    return $isRef;
}
```

Note: there is only a single case when this will not work:

```
$text = array(&$text); // although i don't see why such a structure could be used
isReference($text); // will wrongly return false
```

Obviously you can bypass this limitation by using a random unique key (instead of `0`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [debug_zval_dump](https://www.php.net/debug_zval_dump) to  dump a string representation of an internal `zend` value to output:

```
function isRef(&$val) {
    ob_start();
    debug_zval_dump(&$val);
    $ret = ob_get_clean();
    preg_match('~refcount\((\d+)\)~', $ret, $matches);
    return $matches[1] - 4;
}

$var1 = 'Var1';
$var2 = &$var1; // passed by ref
if(isRef($var2)) echo 'Passed by ref';
```

But be aware of `PHP - 5.4`.

Comment: Interesting idea, however I can't approve it. Checked it in several places and versions, including but not limited to on [onlinephpfunctions](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) website. Also even if I get this code to work, isRef($var1) returns TRUE, when the expected result is FALSE (and $var1 is not a typo).

And yes, I am aware that the version has a huge effect here.

Comment: Yes, this is not a proper solution and I don't know of any but an idea, anyways :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simply checking for the default value seems to work fine in my tests. Obviously it wont work if `$t` is already set to `'x'` but you could change the default value to something totally unlikely to workaround this:

```
function test(&$t='x'){
   if($t!='x') $t = 2;
}
test();   echo $t;  //outputs: null
test($t); echo $t;  //outputs: 2
```