# PHP spot if returned value is a reference or false

Tags: php, reference

I have the following function which modifies an object's property. It also goes down several levels to modify an array in an array that is in an object.

```
public function setProperty($path, $value=null) {
    $path=&$this->getPath($path);
    if ($path === false) return;
    else $path=$value;
}
```

The getPath searches for the value to modify. The logic is as follows:

For example, I send a path to this function `attributes->ids->first` which searches the object if the path exists (ie. the object has an array named attributes, which has an array named ids, which has a key named first).  If it does, it returns a reference to this variable and I change it below.  If it does not, it returns false and my code exits.

The problem is, I don't know how to check if the return value of the `this->getPath` function is indeed a reference, or the function couldn't find the path, and returned false. This way, if the initial value of my variable which I would want to change was false, the script exits at the `if ($path === false) return;` part.

**How could I check if the return value of the** `this->getPath` **function is a reference, or something else?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split getPath in 2 functions : the first one to check if the path exists and the other to get the reference to the path.

Or you can try this solution : [How to check if variable was passed by reference in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958610/how-to-check-if-variable-was-passed-by-reference-in-php)

Comment: The splitting was the way I went with this, and it works fine, thanks:)